# p and 1/p notation for derivatives and integrals

Tags: calculus

I seem to remember in some electrical engineering books, they use the notation 'p' for differentiation and 1/p for integration; or maybe it was the other way around.

Does anyone have any sort of reference or example of the use of this sort of nation?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, e.g. with an example? Because as stated this is quite vague to me

Comment: IIRC, it would be used like this:  px^2 = x.
I'm really fuzzy on the details of this and how it works, but I know I've seen it before

Comment: I have seen $\frac{d^pf(x)}{dx^p}$ and $\frac{d^{-p}f(x)}{dx^{-p}}$ but with $\frac 1p$ nothing rings a bell...

Comment: There's also $D$ as a differential operator, in which case $D^{-1}$ is an integral operator, and you might then see the characteristic equation of a DE written as a polynomial in some variable (e.g. $p$). I also haven't seen it used explicitly as the operator though.

Comment: Surely that would be $px^2=\color{red}{2}x$.

Comment: @zwim It is Laplace Transform that will "ring a bell" with letter $s$ for derivation or $1/s$ for integration for english speaking countries ($p$ and $1/p$ are used in many continental Europe countries)

Comment: @Terry Price Any comment ?

Answer (score 1):

This comes from "Operational calculus" developed at first by Heaviside in the 1890s for solving ordinary differential equations on - say - shaky mathematical grounds and progressively rigorized and being recognized as the **Laplace Transform**, a name that appears in the 1930s ; notations initialy used $p$ and $1/p$ have been kept in many continental Europe countries (see for example this [french table](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Transform%C3%A9e_de_Laplace/Fiche/Table_des_transform%C3%A9es_de_Laplace)), whereas they have been replaced by $s$ for derivation or $1/s$ for integration in english speaking countries. In fact, they are valid under the condition, for example for an intensity $I(t)$ starting with value $I(0)=0$.

An interesting historical text [here](https://fdocuments.in/document/history-of-the-operational-calculus-as-used-in-electric-circuit-analysis.html?page=1), where it is recalled that Laplace had found the method for finding solutions to a differential equation $ay''+by'+cy=0$ with constant coefficients by multiplying it by $e^{-pt}$ (where $p$ is parameter), and integrating it from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$ explaining in particular the presence of terms $1/p$ and $1/p^2$ for simple or double integration resp. under the condition said above $y(0)=0$ and also a fading condition at infinity...

Answer (score 0):

I recall some notation used in 19th century texts.  In a differential equation, where $y$ is an unknown function of $x$, they write $p$ for $dy/dx$ and $q$ for $d^2y/dx^2$.  (If I recall correctly.)  Math texts have not used this for a long time.

Might it be the case that this notation, no longer used in mathematics, is still used in (some) electrical engineering books?

Here is a sample from Dwight, *Tables of Integrals and Other Mathematical Data* (1949).  See 892, 193.1, and 293.2.

[image: Dwight]